# In finite semigroups, the $\mathcal R$-classes are trivial on the set of idempotents

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, semigroups

Let $S$ be a finite semigroup, two elements $s,t \in S$ are called $\mathcal R$-equivalent if $s = t$ or there exists $x,y \in S$ such that $s = tx, t = sy$. Equivalently they generate the same right ideal, i.e.
$$
 sS \cup \{s\} = tS \cup \{t\}.
$$
For more information see [Green's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_relations).

> Now if two idempotents are $\mathcal R$-equivalent, are they equal, i.e. if $e \mathcal R f$ does this imply $e = f$ in finite semigroups?

In general two idempotents $e,f$ are $\mathcal R$-equivalent if and only if $ef = f$ and $fe = e$, as $ex = f$ implies $f = ex = eex = ef$ and similary $fe = e$. If we denote by $E(S)$ the idempotents of $S$, then $e,f \in E(S)$ are $\mathcal R$-equivalent in $S$ iff they are $\mathcal R$-equivalent in $E(S)$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Consider the two-element semigroup $\{e, f\}$ defined by $ee = e$, $ff = f$, $ef = f$ and $fe = e$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Dear Prof. Pin, may I direct your attention to my other question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935436/in-finite-semigroup-if-ef-f-for-e-f-in-es-and-e-xy-f-yx-s-sx